# Can we arrange the order in variant dropdown?

Tags: sxa

Is it possible to arrange the order or select any rendering variant at the top by default in variant dropdown option in Sitecore SXA?

[image]

This is variant dropdown values and we would like to show any value by default.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The default is the first one in the list of variants.

If you change nothing, it will be the first one alphabetically. But you can reorder them in Sitecore (just like all items) and that order is taken into account. So by changing the order you can change the default.

It is mentioned by @gatogordo here - [Default rendering variant for SXA component](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/14058/default-rendering-variant-for-sxa-component)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Changing the sort order of the item will work for you. You will find detailed information about the sort order in this article.

[Sorting Items in Sitecore](https://horizontal.blog/2016/03/11/sorting-items-in-sitecore/)